# Non-existence of independent sets

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I found the following exercise quite intriguing yet had little success getting on the right track. Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) = (\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{P}(\{n\}) = (\frac{1}{2^{n!}})$ for all $n \geq 2$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{1\}) = 1 - \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(\{n\})$. Prove that there are no nontrivial sets $F_1, F_2 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ that are independent. I assumed the opposite for contradiction but arrived nowhere. What is the way to go here?

Comment: Let $n\in A\cap B$ be the smallest. Assume first that $n\neq1$. Then $P(A\cap B)\geq 1/2^{n!}$. On the other hand $P(A)P(B)\leq 1/2^{2\cdot n!}+1/2^{n!+(n+1)!-1}$. But $1/2^{n!}>1/2^{2\cdot n!}+1/2^{n!+(n+1)!-1}$. Therefore $P(A\cap B)>P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: One sec. I am typing. But you can still keep thinking, the idea is similar.

Comment: Assume now that $1\in A\cap B$. Let $C=A^c$ and $D=B^c$. I want to prove that $P(C\cup D)+P(C)P(D)\neq P(C)+P(D)$, which is equivalent to $P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)P(B)$. But $P(C\cup D)= P(C)+P(D)-P(C\cap D)$. Therefore we need to prove $P(C\cap D)\neq P(C)P(D)$. Use now the argument above for $C,D$.

Comment: How do you come up with the second inequality in your first comment? Also, if you'd write up your thoughts as an answer I could upvote and accept it.

Comment: The $1/2^{2\cdot n!}$ is the term $1/2^{n!}$ squared that is in both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. The next term that might be (at most) in the product is $1/2^{n!}\times 1/2^{(n+1)!}$, and then I add all other $1/2^{k}$ for $k=n!+(n+1)!+1,n!+(n+1)!+2,...$. All those terms are not in the product, only some of them. But adding them all just makes the sum larger. This is a geometric progression that adds up to $1/2^{n!+(n+1)!}$. That is why that term is multiplied by $2$ (the $-1$ in the exponent of the bound).

Comment: Thank you @deyore!

Answer (score 1):

We cannot have two non-constant independent random variables on this space. Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables on $(\Omega
,\mathcal F ,P)$ and suppose they are both non-constant. Let $E$ be a
non-empty Borel set in $\mathbb R
$ which does not contain $X(1)$ and $F$ be a non-empty Borel set which

does not contain $Y(1)$. We prove that $$P\{X^{-1}(E)\cap Y^{-1}(F)\}\neq
P\{X^{-1}(E)\}P\{Y^{-1}(F)\}$$ We have $$P\{X^{-1}(E)\}=\sum_{X(n)\in
E}\frac{1}{2^{n!}},P\{Y^{-1}(F)\}=\sum_{Y(n)\in F}^{{}}\frac{1}{%
2^{n!}}$$ and $$P\{X^{-1}(E)\cap Y^{-1}(F)\}=\sum_{X(n)\in E,Y(n)\in
F}^{{}}\frac{1}{2^{n!}}$$. Let $A=\{n:X(n)\in E\}$ and $B=\{n:Y(n)\in F\}$.
If $$P\{X^{-1}(E)\cap Y^{-1}(F)\}=P\{X^{-1}(E)\}P\{Y^{-1}(F)\}$$ then we have 
$$\sum_{n\in A}^{{}}\frac{1}{2^{n!}}\sum_{n\in B}^{{}}\frac{1}{
2^{n!}}=\sum_{n\in A\cap B}^{{}}\frac{1}{2^{n!}}$$ This gives $$
\sum_{n\in A,m\in B}^{{}}\frac{1}{2^{n!+m!}}=\sum_{k\in
A\cap B}^{{}}\frac{1}{2^{k!}}$$. We look at the two sides as expansions to
base $2$ of some number in $(0,1)$. We note that $n!+m!=k!+j!$ implies $%
(n,m)=(k,j)$ or $(n,m)=(j,k)$. To see this suppose, without loss of
generality, $n$ is the least of the integers $n,m,k,j$ and divide both sides
by $(n+1)!.$ We get $\frac{1}{n+1}\in \mathbb N$  a contradiction unless $j$ or $k$ equals $n$. If $k=n$ then we get $m!=j!$
so $m=j$. Similarly $j=n$ implies $m=k$. This proves that $(n,m)=(k,j)$ or $%
(n,m)=(j,k)$. Thus in the sum $\sum_{n\in A,m\in B}^{{}}\frac{1}{%
2^{n!+m!}}$ each term is repeated at most twice. If $k\in A\cap B$ we must
have $\frac{1}{2^{k!}}=\frac{1}{2^{n!+m!}}$ or $\frac{1}{2^{k!}}=\frac{2}{%
2^{n!+m!}}$ for some $n$ and $m>1$ [ by uniqueness of expansions to base $2$
]. Hence $n!+m!=k!$ or $n!+m!-1=(k!)$. We note that $n!+m!$ can never be a
factorial ( as can be seen by a very elementary argument), nor can $n!+m!-1$
be a factorial since $-1$ is not divisible by $2!$ Thus $A\cap B$ is empty.
This contradicts the equation $\sum_{n\in A,m\in B}^{{}}\frac{1}{%
2^{n!+m!}}=\sum_{k\in A\cap B}^{{}}\frac{1}{2^{k!}}$ and the proof
is complete.

Comment: I have copied the proof from another version of latex and there might be some problems in formatting. Sorry about that.

Comment: The formatting is fine. Thank you for your different approach!